# return the first longest string consisting of n consecutive strings taken in the array in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I got this question in my interview:

I got an array strarr of strings and an integer k. My task is to return the first longest string consisting of k consecutive strings taken in the array.

Rules:n being the length of the string array, if n = 0 or k > n or k <= 0 return "".

## Example:

```
LongestConsec(["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas", "theta", "abigail"], 2)
```

output should be "abigailtheta"

Below is the code I have tried ..its not working.

```
public class LongestConsecutives
{
    public static String LongestConsec(string[] strarr, int k)
    {
        string final = String.Join("", strarr.OrderByDescending(s=>s.Length).Take(k)); 
        return final;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        string s1 = LongestConsec(new String[] { "wlwsasphmxx", "owiaxujylentrklctozmymu", "wpgozvxxiu" }, 2); //op="wlwsasphmxxowiaxujylentrklctozmymu"
        string s2 = LongestConsec(new string[] { "itvayloxrp", "wkppqsztdkmvcuwvereiupccauycnjutlv", "vweqilsfytihvrzlaodfixoyxvyuyvgpck" }, 2);//op="wkppqsztdkmvcuwvereiupccauycnjutlvvweqilsfytihvrzlaodfixoyxvyuyvgpck"
        string s3 = LongestConsec(new String[] { "zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas" }, -2);//op=""
        string s4 = LongestConsec(new String[] { "it", "wkppv", "ixoyx", "3452", "zzzzzzzzzzzz" }, 3);//op="ixoyx3452zzzzzzzzzzzz"
        string s5 = LongestConsec(new String[] { "it", "wkppv", "ixoyx", "3452", "zzzzzzzzzzzz" }, 15);//op=""
        string s6 = LongestConsec(new String[] { "it", "wkppv", "ixoyx", "3452", "zzzzzzzzzzzz" }, 0);//op=""
        string s7 = LongestConsec(new String[] { }, 3);//op=""
        string s8 = LongestConsec(new String[] { "zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas", "theta", "abigail" }, 2);//op="abigailtheta"
        string s9 = LongestConsec(new String[] { "ejjjjmmtthh", "zxxuueeg", "aanlljrrrxx", "dqqqaaabbb", "oocccffuucccjjjkkkjyyyeehh" }, 1);//op="oocccffuucccjjjkkkjyyyeehh"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this your homework or ours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `.Distinct()` call in your LINQ for removing duplicates.

```
public static String LongestConsec(string[] strarr, int k)
{
    string final = String.Join("", 
        strarr.Distinct()                       // Remove Duplicates
              .OrderByDescending(s => s.Length) // Order by Length
              .Take(k)                          // Take from List
    );

    return final;
}
```

After this modify, you will get your expected output:

```
string target = LongestConsec(new string[] { "zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas", "theta", "abigail"}, 2);
// target = "abigailtheta"
```

But you are still missing the `IF` cases for completed your described Rules:

> if n = 0 or k > n or k <= 0 return ""

---

### Update

As Vladimir Pavelka points out in the Comment, you just need a way to store the initial index of the word order. You can do it with a `Dictionary` something like this:

```
public static String LongestConsec(string[] strarr, int k)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < strarr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(strarr[i]))  // Preventing duplicates
        {
            dict.Add(strarr[i], i + 1);
        }
    }

    string final = String.Join("",
        dict.OrderByDescending(s => s.Key.Length)
            .Take(k)
            .OrderBy(s => s.Value)
            .Select(s => s.Key)
    );

    return final;
}
```

Comment: you can't apply order by, because it will change the output here. like `["xyz","Amit1234","mp"]` should result `xyzAmit1234` not `Amit1234xyz`.

Comment: @AmitKumar where is it stated that the ordering matters?

Comment: @AmitKumar Thats legit expectation, but not mentioned by OP. The lack of proper describing the question makes it hard.

Comment: yes @AmitKumar is correct.. i want that output only.

Comment: Cmon, Select into tuple <word, initial index>, order by word, Take(k), order back by initial index, string.Join.. no biggie

Comment: @Smartis Just `String.Join("", strarr.Distinct().Select((s, idx) => (s, idx)).OrderByDescending(x => x.s.Length).Take(k).OrderBy(x => x.idx));`

Comment: @VladiPavelka As cool as your solution is (and proves that you have quite impressive knowledge about C#7.3), it's missing a `.Select(x => x.s)` at the end. Post this as seperate anwser and you will have my upvote.

Comment: @Smartis Thanks ! : P

Answer (score 2):

After discussion with Smartis:

```
public static String LongestConsec(string[] strarr, int k) =>
    String.Join("", 
        strarr.Distinct() // note: this won't change order
              .Select((s, idx) => (s, idx)) // store initial index
              .OrderByDescending(x => x.s.Length) // longest words first
              .Take(k)
              .OrderBy(x => x.idx) // restore original order
              .Select(x => x.s));
```